# How can I use date and time selectors in OneNote 2010?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

The default note template in OneNote 2010 has date and time selectors underneath the note title, which automatically inputs the date and time when the note is created and can be manually adjusted by clicking on the calendar/ clock icons.

How can I use these date and time selectors elsewhere in my notes? And can I attach them to note containers?

I am aware that date and time can be inserted from the Insert ribbon, but these are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. The date/time selectors underneath the title are a feature of the title, and not a standard date/time input. [The only options provided in this list are the standard date/time inserts you've mentioned.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/onenote-help/insert-the-time-and-date-in-your-notes-HA010231421.aspx) Still I've poked around extensivly and there aren't any hidden options for this, and I have been unable to find anything about this elsewhere, not even an add-in.

OneNote is genearlly just for storing ideas and notes, and so I guess theres no need for a date picker as you'd only need the date the entry was added.

If you are looking to create a form for others to complete you'd be better off with SharePoint/Infopath or even Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I thought as much, but thought it worthwhile asking. The reason for me wanting this facility is because I'm keeping a logbook, and there's a requirement for timestamping notes. I could just create a new tab, but that breaks the continuity of the notes, which really need to be organised thematically than chronologically.

Comment: No worries @James. If it helps (and if you didn't know already), if you decide to just use the insert date/time feature you can add the date/time the same way as with the insert function by hitting alt+shift+f. Alternatively you may find Excel works quite well for a log book, or even better, if you're company can get hold of it (even a basic free version will do) SharePoint will allow you to create records with commentary and a wealth of other data, and have the date/time created logged automatically, then you can sort the records by that.

Comment: Yeh, that's the keyboard shortcut I'm using to manually timestamp entries (and just format them in bold). Excel wouldn't quite work for me, as I'm using OneNote's features, and Sharepoint... Well, I'm just a student making my own design notes - it might be overkill for my needs. Would be a nice feature to have in the next edition of Office, though.

Comment: You do get SharePoint with the right version of Office 365 :) Ah well then, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score -1):

The following GEM add-in might be helpful -- there may also be other add-ins from GEM or others which address your need...

http://www.onenotegem.com/onenote-reminder.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please see the guidelines on [recommending software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). In particular, you should explain how the software you're suggesting answers the question.